# Can we choose the eigenvalues of a product of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a product of matrices $P = D_1 A D_2 A^T D_1$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are diagonal, I would like to choose $D_1$ and $D_2$ so that the eigenvalues of $P$ are the diagonal entries of $D_1$. Is this possible?

Comment: So to be clear, $A$ is fixed and we can't change it, and we want to find (for each possible $A$) diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ so that the eigenvalues of $P$ are the diagonal entries of $D_1$? What  about the solution $D_1=0$?

Answer (score 0):

$P=D_1AD_2A^TD_1$ (GIVEN)

$D_1^T = D_1$ (Since $D_1$ is Diagonal )

So $P$ can be written as like $P=D_1AD_2A^TD_1 = (D_1A)D_2(D_1A)^T$

So Eigen values of $P$ are diagonal entries of $D_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't believe there is any reason to believe that $(D_1 A)$ is an orthogonal matrix in general.